# how to create a new column with values from other two columns by group (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to deal with a problem with data handling like this:
Asume I have a df:

```
 ID first  second 
  1    14    16      
  1    14    16      
  1    14    16           
  2    20    32     
  2    20    32      
  2    20    32        
  2    20    32
```

So basically what I want to do is to create a new column (combination) that will take the unique values from first and second per ID (something like this)

```
    ID first  second  combination
      1    14    16      14
      1    14    16      16
      1    14    16           
      2    20    32      20
      2    20    32      32
      2    20    32        
      2    20    32
```

So far I used:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(combination = case_when(
  first  <= second ~ first, 
  second >= first ~ second,
  TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

But it is not working at all, any clues, please?

Comment: Do you want `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(combination = sort(unique(c(first, second)))[1:n()]) %>% ungroup()`?

Comment: Yes, that makes the job!!